# What topics can I ask about here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

What's on-topic or not will naturally evolve during private beta but should finally be condensed into this part of the FAQ: https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I would think it easier to discuss matter here at meta first (community wiki answer for easy editing) and transfer to the FAQ once a concensus is reached.

Especially the content that overlaps with other existing sites should be properly excluded.

Comment: We should wait a bit to fill out information this hard lined

Comment: Yeah, I guess I got carried away a little. We should give it a few weeks to let voting and discussing iron out what we actually want... but meta posts do not age away in a matter of weeks and we could proceed discussing it as we like, @ZachSaucier

Comment: Right, but there's no point in trying to fill out the specifics below if it's going to change over the next few weeks over and over again. IMO it'd be better to delete it for now and repost it when the site is more ready

Comment: I see it as a living document, changing as we develop our ideas on what is on-topic and what is not. If anyone has a good first shot on it, why not put it down right now. It will not hurt if it is changed later but if it is a good idea then that part will simply prevail.

Comment: Please don't post such broad questions. Open a separate meta question for each debated point of the scope.

Comment: Just reiterating what was said above, but it simply too soon for a thread like this. It is better bring up specific concerns when and if they become a significant problem/misunderstanding in actual practice... rather than trying to anticipate and outline every on and off topic problem in one giant thread.

Answer (score 3):

### If your question is about:

- ...
- ...

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

### But please note that the following is *off topic*

- ...
- ...
- Questions directly related to Linux/Unix issues. Please use the [Unix & Linux Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).
- General programming questions will be better off on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com).
- Questions specific to the Raspberry Pi: [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

For more help, see ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](/help/dont-ask).

---

Before asking a new question please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. Bear in mind it’s also fine to [answer your own questions](/helpcenter/self-answer) if you sucessfully find an answer on your own!

Comment: I think that you could, legitimately, add "Questions specific to the Arduino, please use [Arduino](http://arduino.stackexchange.com)", as an Arduino is as likely to be used for IoT applications as the Raspberry Pi is.